# Multi-statement scripts in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a document
PUT test/_doc/1

```
{
    "counter" : 1,
    "tags" : ["red"]
}
```

I am using script to update my content of the documents
POST test/_doc/1/_update

```
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

POST test/_doc/1/_update

```
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.new_field = 'value_of_new_field'"
}
```

This two scripts are working fine individually, I want to use these two script statements in a single "_update" API.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, simply add a semicolon at the end of each statement

Comment: {
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag)"; "ctx._source.new_field = 'value_of_new_field'",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "tag" : "blue"
        }
    }
}
Something like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add semicolons between statements, like this:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.tag); ctx._source.new_field = 'value_of_new_field';",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "tag": "blue"
    }
  }
}
```